# unable to get ElementHandle when filtering puppeteer elements

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

I am trying to use Puppeteer to scrape data from https://pagespeed.web.dev - I need to be able to take screenshots of the results and while it would be much simpler to use Google's own API to get the raw data, I can't screenshot the actual results that way. The challenge I'm having is filtering out DOM elements while still retaining the `ElementHandle` nature of the objects. For example, getting the "This URL" / "Origin" buttons:

In a normal JS console, I would run this:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('button')].filter(b => b.innerText === 'This URL')
```

This would give me an Array of DOM elements that I could then run `click()` on or whatever.

I have tried a number of ways to get Puppeteer to give me a usable `ElementHandle` object and they have all returned an array of objects, with the sole member of that object being an `__incrementalDOMData` object:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto(`https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=${url}`)
await page.waitForSelector(homepageWaitSelector, { visible: true })

// here's where the fun starts
const buttons = await page.$$eval('button', buttons => buttons.filter(button => button.innerText === 'This URL'))
const buttons = await page.$$eval('button', buttons => buttons.map(b => b.innerText).filter(t => t === 'This URL'))

// This one seems to run because the list of elements returned has the right length, but I can never get a breakpoint to catch inside the `evaluate` method, nor does a `console.log` statement actually print.
const buttons = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const b = [...document.querySelectorAll('button')].filter(b => b.innerText === 'This URL')
  return b
})
```

All of those methods end up returning something like this:

```js
[{
  __incrementalDOMData: {
    j: ['class', 'the-classes-used'],
    key: 'a key',
    v: true
}]
```

Because there are so many buttons, and because the class names are all random and reused, I can't just target the ones I want (I mean I suppose I could build a *super* precise selector), filter them, and then return not just the filtered data but the actual elements themselves. Is what I'm asking for even possible?

Comment: You [don't have to use Puppeteer's click](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#avoiding-pageevaluate-when-trusted-events-arent-necessary). Just use the browser's native click inside an evaluate if that's already working for you. Is the issue timing? Why do you need a breakpoint and what are you trying to accomplish, exactly? What's `homepageWaitSelector`? Thanks

Comment: You're right, I didn't need to click on the actual element, just evaluate a click in the context. Also discovered I didn't need to comb through all the buttons - the parent div was unique enough to get me what I needed, then since it should only have two buttons, I used `:first-child` and `:last-child` to get the two.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ggorlen's comment above I simplified my approach and got something working without an overly complex selector or logic:

```js
const buttonContainer = await page.$('div.R3HzDf.ucyZQe')

const thisUrlButton = await buttonContainer.$(':first-child')
await thisUrlButton.evaluate(b => b.click())
await page.screenshot({ path: 'homepage.png' })

const originButton = await buttonContainer.$(':last-child')
await originButton.evaluate(b => b.click())
await page.screenshot({ path: 'origin.png' })
```